# How to get a consensus of multiple sequence alignments using Biopython?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I am trying to get a consensus sequence from my multiple alignment**s** files (*fasta* format).

I have a few *fasta* files each containing multiple sequence alignments. When I try to run this function below I get an `AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'get_alignment_length'`.

I haven't been able to find any code examples for this using `AlignIO.parse`, I only saw examples using `AlignIO.read`.

```
def get_consensus_seq(filename):

    alignments = (AlignIO.parse(filename,"fasta"))
    summary_align = AlignInfo.SummaryInfo(alignments)
    consensus_seq = summary_align.dumb_consensus(0.7,"N")
    print(consensus_seq)
```

Comment: Does each file has only one alignment?

Comment: @Vovin no they are all multiple sequence alignments

Comment: So each file can have several alignments (**n**), you have several files (**m**). The resulted number of alignments: **n*m**?

Comment: @Vovin no. I am only reading one file at a time so the number of alignments is just n.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your situation right, the problem is the impossibility to get `SummaryInfo` from several alignments. They should be united into one.

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from pathlib import Path
from itertools import chain

import Bio
from Bio import AlignIO
from Bio.Align import MultipleSeqAlignment
from Bio.Align.AlignInfo import SummaryInfo


SeqRecord = Bio.SeqRecord.SeqRecord


def get_consensus_seq(filename: Path | str) -> SeqRecord:
    common_alignment = MultipleSeqAlignment(
        chain(*AlignIO.parse(filename, "fasta"))
    )
    summary = SummaryInfo(common_alignment)
    consensus = summary.dumb_consensus(0.7, "N")
    return consensus
```

Comment: Thanks a million @Vovin! Worked exactly how I wanted it to

Comment: @Angie I am glad to help! If you estimate my answer as useful, please could you upvote it?

Comment: I tried but I don't have enough reputation to vote :(